# Loading Rdata files from url

Tags: r, url, loading, dimension

I'm having difficulty loading a file so that it doesn't lose its dimensions. So here is where I'm at:

```
> mood_data <- read.table("http://www.psychology.mcmaster.ca/bennett/psy710/datasets/mood_data.Rdata")
```

If I do this it just gives me all the information disorganized in one line. I also tried:

```
> mood_data <- url("http://www.psychology.mcmaster.ca/bennett/psy710/datasets/mood_data.Rdata")
> load(mood_data)
```

If I do this I get this weird stuff that doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 15):

You should use `load` for `.RData` files. This works for me.

```
> load(url("http://www.psychology.mcmaster.ca/bennett/psy710/datasets/mood_data.Rdata"))
> ls()
[1] "mood.data"
> head(mood.data)
     group mood
1 pleasant    6
2 pleasant    5
3 pleasant    4
4 pleasant    7
5 pleasant    7
6 pleasant    5
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! One question though, why does "mood.data" become the data frame name?

Comment: @BrettCochrane This was the variable name when `.Rdata` file was created.

Comment: @y3trgfhsfgr an `.Rdata` file is being saved using the `save` function. When it is being saved, this function takes the name of this data as it was parsed to it (its actual name in the global environment). For example `save(myData, file ="...")`. Then, when loaded using `load`, this file is being saved within the global environment under its original name ("myData").